# How to insert direct current symbol in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typography, typesetting

Does anyone know how to insert the direct current symbol (⎓) in Adobe Illustrator please? I copy and paste the character into a text frame but it becomes a cross square which cannot be displayed correctly. I switched to a number of different font types but no luck. I also tried to insert a symbol from Adobe Illustrator but cannot find any.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As it's a technical symbol, you should look for a font containing such symbols, as **Cambria Math** font.

If copy/paste doesn't help, use the **Glyph Panel** to look for it: with the insert text cursor active, click twice the symbol at the Glyph panel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel, Cambria Math font does work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option — without using a special font file — is to actually draw the symbol from 4 basic rectangles, group these, and copy paste where needed.

[image]